# Ubuntu print output of "find" and "exec" to file

Tags: command-line, find

I have a command which list outs events of "Magento 2", which is working fine in the terminal.

I want it's output to be printed into a file but none of the below code works:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -n -H -A 2 -T "eventManager->dispatch(" {} \ | tee ~/MAGE2EVENTS.txt
```

Neither this one:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -n -H -A 2 -T "eventManager->dispatch(" {} \ >> ~/MAGE2EVENTS.txt
```

I see 'exec' has been used in this code which shows error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

So how to print the terminal output of this command to file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `-exec` command must be terminated with a `\;` or `+`. The `\;` will cause `find` to run the command once for each file, and the `+` will make it try and run the command on many files at once, making it more efficient. Since your `grep` is using `-H` (print filenames), the `+` is the better choice. So add `+` at the end of your find command:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -n -H -A 2 -T "eventManager->dispatch(" {} + |
     tee ~/MAGE2EVENTS.txt
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as the best one if possible.